# How to use WHERE clauses to optimise SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, where-clause

I have a very simple query.

```
SELECT top 100 *
FROM logs
WHERE description LIKE '%5488826%'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

However it contains a LIKE clause which is searching a largish text field.

I know the table only has (for example) 200200 rows

(I'm only interested in finding something that happened in a row id > 200000).

I *tried* to optimise the query by adding in

```
 SELECT top 100 *
 FROM logs
 WHERE  ID > 200000 
 AND description LIKE '%5488826%'
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

my thinking was that SQL would run the `ID > 200000` constraint first and that would help speed up the query, but it still takes minutes to run, what should I do to make this run faster.

EDIT:
ID is PK and indexed

Comment: What does an `EXPLAIN` get you? If you really have 200200 rows, you'd think the optimizer would indeed do what you suggest and it'd take a second or so. (Unless "largish" means "megabytes", at least)

Comment: 1. what is your dbms? 2. show us your explain plan output

Comment: I'm in MS SQL Server, I guess EXPLAIN is the query analyser, will check it out...

Comment: If you do not have indexes (and it sounds as if you do not use them) you need to [read this article at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647793.aspx#scalenetchapt14%20_topic8).

Comment: Please post the execution plan. Assuming `ID` is the clustered index I would have expected that it would just scan it in reverse and stop when either 100 matching rows are found or it reaches the end of the id range. Maybe the delay is for some other reason (blocking by long held open transactions for example)

Comment: You have two "sins" in terms of querying: (1) using `LIKE '%....%'` makes it impossible for SQL Server to use any indexes, and (2) using `SELECT *` will also mean SQL Server will most likely have to scan the whole clustered index (basically a table scan) to get your data. No way to optimize **this** - you need to rewrite this.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to create a temp-table with only the entries with an id > 200000, and query that to see if it makes any difference:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM logs WHERE id > 200000;

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE description LIKE '%5488824%' ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
SELECT top 100 * from
(select description FROM logs  WHERE  ID > 200000 )  s
where s.description LIKE '%5488826%'  
ORDER BY s.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try subquery first constraint. Depends on DB which you use you can try something like:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM (
SELECT ID, description FROM logs WHERE ID > 200000
) AS data
JOIN
   logs 
ON
   logs.id = data.id
WHERE
   data.description LIKE '%5488826%'
ORDER BY
   ID DESC
```

OR (for SQL Server -- with CTE and read uncommitted hint):

```
;WITH data AS (
    SELECT ID, description FROM logs WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ID > 200000
)
SELECT
  logs.*
FROM
  data 
  JOIN
    logs WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON
    logs.id = data.id
WHERE
  data.description LIKE '%5488826%'
```

And make sure you have index on `id` column.

Answer (score -1):

Very short answer ;-) Add an index to the columns.

Comment: Explain why index could help (on each columns)?

Comment: I love it how you guys come up with query tuning suggestions without seeing its actual execution plan ;)

Comment: Oh, I mean: Add an index to the columns "id" and "description"